# How to create a more button to load the next batch of photos with my script

Tags: javascript, php, instagram

I got this neat little Instagram script that pulls hashtag posts that skips the API process, but I don't know how to load the next batch. It will only load up to 6 photos at a time.

I tried something like this

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
 $(window).scroll(function () {
         if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
      return $insta_array;
         }
 });

    </script>
```

But never had any luck..

```
        <?php

        function scrape_insta_hash($tag) {
  $insta_source = file_get_contents('https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/'.$tag.'/'); // instagrame tag url
  $shards = explode('window._sharedData = ', $insta_source);
  $insta_json = explode(';</script>', $shards[1]);
  $insta_array = json_decode($insta_json[0], TRUE);
  return $insta_array; // this return a lot things print it and see what else you need
}

$tag = "beachglass";
$results_array = scrape_insta_hash($tag);
$limit = 500; // provide the limit thats important because one page only give some images then load more have to be clicked

/*for ($i=$limit; $i >= 0; $i--) */ for ($i=0; $i < $limit; $i++){

  if(array_key_exists($i,$results_array['entry_data']['TagPage'][0]["graphql"]["hashtag"]["edge_hashtag_to_media"]["edges"])){
    $latest_array = $results_array['entry_data']['TagPage'][0]["graphql"]["hashtag"]["edge_hashtag_to_media"]["edges"][$i]["node"];

      $newPosting = [
        "image"=>$latest_array['display_url'],
        "thumbnail"=>$latest_array['thumbnail_src'],
        "instagram_id"=>$latest_array['id'],
        "caption"=>$latest_array['caption']['edge_media_to_caption']['edges'][0]["node"]["text"],
        "link"=>"https://www.instagram.com/p/".$latest_array['shortcode'],
        "date"=>$latest_array['taken_at_timestamp']
      ];

       echo '<div class="photo"><a href="'.$newPosting['image'].'"><img src="'.$newPosting['thumbnail'].'"></a><div class="caption">'.$newPosting['caption'].'</div></div>';

  }
}

        ?>
```

I can get this to display real results, just not load beyond 60 or so images.

Comment: Instagram itself seems to use a GraphQL API, so I am not sure that page-scraping approach will work. I assume the API is public - can you try that instead?

Answer (score 0):

What can you do is use AJAX and add the limit of the posts. Suppose this is the div. You have to store the index of the posts in the div Do this

```php
echo '<div index="'. $i .'" class="photo"><a href="'.$newPosting['image'].'"><img src="'.$newPosting['thumbnail'].'"></a><div class="caption">'.$newPosting['caption'].'</div></div>';
```

And when the div is at the bottom, you can send a ajax like this

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  let index = $('.photo:last').attr("index"); // get the last div's index
  if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
    $.ajax({ //create an ajax request to your .php file
      type: "POST",
      url: "yourphppage.php",
      data: 'moreposts=' + index, // add a a parameter
      dataType: "html", //expect html to be returned
      success: function(msg) {
     }
    });
  }
});
```

Now make your `$limit` variable a global variable, So you can edit it's value in the scope. Like this

```php
$limit = 6; //default limit

if (isset($_POST["moreposts"])) {
   $lastindex = (int)$_POST["moreposts"];
   $limit = $lastindex * 2 // or anything you want
}

function scrape_insta_hash($tag) {
  ...
for ($i=0; $i < $limit; $i++){
...
```

Personally. I don't recommend webscraping. It is an ugly way of retriving data. They can also change their markup anyday.